# Runtime error 1004 - Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have recorded the macro -below - to import a csv file

If I try to modify the name of the file to import a different one (say 2017-05-01) it gives me error: Runtime error 1004 - Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range.

If I modify the range it works, but not when I modify the file name. 
My excel is running on a Mac. The only item I can think of is that my disc is encrypted... any idea?

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/dl/Documents/Annual_renewal/262_3297_2017_04_30.csv", _
        Destination:=Range("A411"))
        .Name = "262_3297_2017_04_30"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Excel 2016? It's a sandboxed app, which requires approval from the user before files can be opened. This site appears to have advice for your specific problem: https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/systemsbiology/staff/dyer/software/excelvbafileopen/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was trying to import sheet from Desktop folder which was causing "Runtime error 1004 - Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range".

Then I copied same file to Excel home directory "**/Users/userName/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Application Support/yourFolder/YourFile**" and this fixed the error.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;/Users/userName/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Application Support/yourFolder/YourFile/Annual_renewal/262_3297_2017_04_30.csv", _
    Destination:=Range("A411"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration of Brendan Shanks's post. He was spot re Mac OS X's quirky file permission issue. I'm just trying to save frustrated people's time a bit more by posting the exact answer (for me) from the longish article.

Essentially each file needs to be explicitly granted file permission to Excel for each file, when it's first opened. This is done by calling the following function:

```
Function grantFileAccess(filePermissionCandidates)
    grantFileAccess = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates) 
End Function
```

How to use this function? Call this function for all the files you want to use. If it's the first time the file is being opened (i.e. Excel doesn't have the permission yet), it'll prompt the user to grant the permission.

```
grantFileAccess (Array("PATH_TO_FILE/file.csv", "PATH_TO_FILE/file2.csv"))
```